# Error: Undefined binding(s) quando eu vou dar um submit - React , axios e nodeJS

Tags: node.js, react, http, axios, try-catch

Estou tentando fazer um sistema de login , ja escrevi o código e quando eu faço pelo insomnia ele funciona perfeitamente , porém quando eu fiz a conexão com o front-end utilizando o axios ele não consegue enviar os dados digitados para o banco de dados. Já testei algumas coisas: tentei dar um `alert` fora do `try` e ele retorna exatamente o que digitei , porém quando eu tento colocar o mesmo`alert`dentro do `try` ele me retorna a string que eu digitei como `undefined`.
O erro que ele retorna é :

```
C:\users\mathe\desktop\eventos\backend\node_modules\knex\lib\query\compiler.js:98
      throw new Error(
            ^

Error: Undefined binding(s) detected when compiling FIRST. Undefined column(s): [email] query: select `password` from `users` where `email` = ? limit ?
    at QueryCompiler_SQLite3.toSQL (C:\users\mathe\desktop\eventos\backend\node_modules\knex\lib\query\compiler.js:98:13)
    at Builder.toSQL (C:\users\mathe\desktop\eventos\backend\node_modules\knex\lib\query\builder.js:97:44)
    at C:\users\mathe\desktop\eventos\backend\node_modules\knex\lib\runner.js:31:36
    at C:\users\mathe\desktop\eventos\backend\node_modules\knex\lib\runner.js:277:24
    at async login (C:\users\mathe\desktop\eventos\backend\src\controller\userController.js:40:26)
```

código do React :

```
import React  , {useState}from 'react';
import './stylesheet.css';
import {useHistory} from 'react-router-dom'
import api from '../services/api'

export default function Login() {
    const [email , setEmail] = useState("");
    const [pass , setPassword] = useState("");

    const history = useHistory();

    async function handleLogin(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        const data = {
            email,
            pass
        }
        
        try{
            const response = await api.get('/login' , {data})

            localStorage.setItem('id' , response.data.user.id)
            localStorage.setItem('nome',response.data.user.nome)

            alert(response.data.user);
            history.push('/calendario')
        }catch(err){
            alert("nope");
        }
    }
    return(
        <div className='Logon'>
            <h1>App de eventos</h1>
            <form className='login' onSubmit={handleLogin}>
            <p>Login : <input placeholder='Digite seu login' value={email}
            onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)}/></p>
            <p>{email}</p>
            <p>Senha : <input type='password' placeholder='Digite sua senha'value={pass}
            onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)}/></p> 
            <button type="submit">ENTRAR</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
};
```

código do Back-end:

```
const connection = require('../database/connection');

module.exports = {
async login(req , resp){
        const {email , pass} = req.body;

        const password = await connection('users').where('email',email).select('password').first();

        const check_pass = bcrypt.compareSync(pass,password.password);
        
        const user = await connection('users').where('email' , email);

        if(!check_pass){
            return resp.json({ae : 'deu nao'});
        }else{
            return resp.json({user})
        }
    }
}
```

código do routes para o node.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const routes = express.Router();

const userController = require('./controller/userController');

routes.get('/login' , userController.login);

module.exports = routes;
```

node.js:

```
const routes = require('./routes');
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(routes);

app.listen(3333);
```

Comment: Tente as seguintes alterações, na requisição axios tire os {} de data, deixe só o campo data e no backend, faça condições caso ele envie os campos vazios, antes de pesquisar no banco de dados

Comment: eu fiz isso , retirei os colchetes e fiz um if para dar um console.log caso email esteja undefinied , acabou que ele deu o console.log. Mas minha principal duvida é , por que quando eu dou alert fora do try ele retorna justamente o que eu digitei ,e dentro do try ele retorna como undefinied

Comment: Acabei resolvendo só trocando para o método POST , vou responder e deixar aqui caso alguém tenha a mesma dúvida.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acabei resolvendo apenas trocando o método GET para POST .
Por mais que esteja buscando informações dentro do banco de dados é necessário estar em método POST , pois ele é necessário toda vez ao enviar um formulário ou arquivo.
O método GET só seria viável caso fosse apenas buscar uma informação do servidor sem um formulário.